# Creating Listview dynamically in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, dynamic-list

I Have a two dimensional string `array`,

I want to create a 3 column list-view, that display data from the string array, it should have the same number of rows that the size of the string array.

This is my string array:

```
String[][] data = {
   {"001", "JOHN ","1001" },
   {"002", "SIBIN", "1002" },
   {"003", "TOM ",   "1003" },
   {"004", "FREEDY", "1004" }
   };
```

I want to display it in a `Listview` like

```
ID    NAME   VACANCY ID
001   JOHN    1001
002   SIBIN   1002
003   TOM     1003
004   FREEDY  1004
```

Also when I click a list-view item, it redirect to another page with the listview id

How is this possible?  I am new in the android development, I know only the basics, and I only know how to create `listview`.

Comment: what have you already tried?

Comment: Hi Rajitha, i tried to create a listview with 3 column, but i dont know how to add dynamically data to listview from the string array

Comment: can you post your code? you will have to create a custom adapter for the ListView.

Comment: @Sibinfrancis Go through the links provided in below...i am sure u answer is there only...No can write a code, base on your requirement, u have to crack this out from the below link.

Comment: Thanx Rajitha...thatis the right way.. but why people downvote my question?? iam  new in android.. iam not an expert..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for that you need a customize list view first you should add a listview in your main.xml(just an eg) file then create a class like this

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
      private final Context context;
      private final String[] values;
      DataHelper dh;

      public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] values) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;

        dh=new DataHelper(getApplicationContext());
      }

      @Override
      public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_name, parent, false);
       textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textname);

        textView.setText(values[position]);
        // Change the icon for Windows and iPhone
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(View v) 
               {
                   Toast.makeText(this,""+values[position],10000).show();
               }
               });


        return rowView;
}
```

R.layout.list_name this will be the new xml file which will load the contents to the list view

and the the final step just in your on create method do this

```
con = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_listView); 
 MySimpleArrayAdapter adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,  R.id.main_listView ,data);// data is String array valu to be added in list view
    //setting the adapter
    con.setAdapter(adapter);
```