# How to display multiple columns from a prepopoulated database in list view?

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite

This is my main activity in which I am using a pre-populated database. I am trying to display the rows in list view. There are five columns in my database out of which I want to display all columns except id.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private IngHelper dbIngHelper = null;
private Cursor curname=null;
private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = null;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView myList; 
    myList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    dbIngHelper = new IngHelper(this);
    dbIngHelper.createDB();
    dbIngHelper.openDB();


    fillData();
}


public void fillData(){

    //ListView myList; 
    ListView myList; 
    myList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    curname=dbIngHelper.getCursor();
    startManagingCursor(curname);
    String[] columns = new String[] {
            IngHelper.COLUMN_ID,
            IngHelper.COLUMN_NAME,
            IngHelper.COLUMN_NATURE,
            IngHelper.COLUMN_SECTION,
            IngHelper.COLUMN_PENALTY
      };

    int[] to = new int[] { 
            R.id.id,
            R.id.name,
            R.id.nature,
            R.id.penalty,
            R.id.section
          };

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, R.layout.activity_main, 
            curname, 
            columns, 
            to);



    myList.setAdapter(adapter);



myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,int position, long   id) {
   //Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
   // Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);


   }
});
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

class IngAdapter extends CursorAdapter{
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    IngAdapter(Cursor c){
        super(MainActivity.this,c);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View row, Context ctxt, Cursor c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        IngHolder holder=(IngHolder)row.getTag();
        holder.populateFrom(c,dbIngHelper);


    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context cxtx, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inf = getLayoutInflater();
        View row=inf.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        IngHolder holder = new IngHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
        return(row);
    }

}

static class IngHolder{
    private TextView name=null;
   //   private TextView nature=null;
    //private TextView section=null;
    //private TextView penalty=null;

    IngHolder(View row){

        name=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.name);

    }

    void populateFrom(Cursor c,IngHelper r){

        name.setText(r.getName(c));


    }


}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

This is database class IngHelper.java

```
  public class IngHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


private static final String DATABASE_PATH =        "//data//data//com.example.db//databases//";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "traffic.sqlite";
private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION = 1;
public static final String TABLE_NAME="mumbai";
public static final String COLUMN_ID="_id";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME="name";
public static final String COLUMN_NATURE="nature";
public static final String COLUMN_SECTION="section";
public static final String COLUMN_PENALTY="penalty";


public SQLiteDatabase dbSqlite;

private final Context myCnt;

public IngHelper (Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
    this.myCnt=context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void createDB(){

    boolean dbExist = DBExist();

    if(!dbExist){

        this.getReadableDatabase();

        copyDBFromResource();
    }
}

private boolean DBExist(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;

    try{
        String dbPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null,     SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
        db.setLockingEnabled(true);
        db.setVersion(1);
    }catch(SQLiteException e){
        Log.e("SqlHelper", "db nt found");
        }

    return db != null ? true : false;
}

private void copyDBFromResource(){
    InputStream iS =null;
    OutputStream oS = null;
    String dbFilePath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

    try{
         iS = myCnt.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

         oS = new FileOutputStream(dbFilePath);

         byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
         int length;
         while((length=iS.read(buffer))>0){
             oS.write(buffer, 0, length);
         }

         oS.flush();
         oS.close();
         iS.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        throw new Error("Prob copyin db from resource file.");
    }

}

public void openDB()throws SQLException {
    String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    dbSqlite = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(dbSqlite != null)
    {
        dbSqlite.close();
    }
    super.close();
}


public Cursor getCursor(){
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    qBuilder.setTables(TABLE_NAME);
    String[] asColmToRetrn = new String[] {COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_NATURE, COLUMN_SECTION, COLUMN_PENALTY};

    Cursor mCur = qBuilder.query(dbSqlite, asColmToRetrn, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (mCur != null) {
       mCur.moveToFirst();
      }
      return mCur;

     }



public String getName(Cursor c){
    return(c.getString(1));


}

}
```

There are two xml files. This is activity_main.xml... It has a list View.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >



<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Another layout is row.xml file. Here I am creating a text View for each column in my database.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nature"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/section"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/penalty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"

    android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am getting a blank list as output with a list entry for each row but the data cannot be seen. please give some suggestions to resolve the problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953862/creating-listview-dynamically-in-android/14954033#14954033

Check the link its an ans for your question. :)