# I can't figure out how to make a table in android, that gives a summary of the hours registered

Tags: android, layout, label

I find designing my android App really hard. Don't even know where to start. I just want to make a simple table like this:

didn't allow me to post a picture.
here's the link:

[image]

It has to be created with code since the 5 rows(15/04-15 - hverdag -1337 - 3 -2 and so on)  are depending on how many registered hours the person has created in a time interval of a week. So it could be 1 or 100 rows.

Comment: did you try using a listview? you can easily manage to create your columns in a list view, and you can populate it with whatever data you have.(from db) here is a link for you at first glance : http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2009/02/15/multicolumn-listview-in-android/

Comment: also another one with db usage : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14996683/how-to-display-multiple-columns-from-a-prepopoulated-database-in-list-view please check that post and see how you can create a table with list-view.

Comment: Thx checked out ur links, and found a solution to my problem.

Comment: happy to help you mike. I will put it as answer so that you can confirm and others can go over them. happy coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily manage your task by creating columns in a listview, and you can populate its adapter via data from anywhere you want. Here are some links for showing that stuff :

For creating a multicolumn ListView from [this](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2009/02/15/multicolumn-listview-in-android/) link.

and for showing how to populate your custom adapter follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14996683/how-to-display-multiple-columns-from-a-prepopoulated-database-in-list-view) link.

Hope this helps.