# How to change simple_list_item_1 to custom list ?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I write this code for get data from DataBase and show in listView. I want to show my data in my custom List with 3 textView and 1 ImageView. how can i do that?

This is my code :

```
private void Name() {
        ListView tvName = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvListOfObject);
        DataBase infoName = new DataBase(this);
        infoName.open();
        ArrayList<String> dataName = infoName.getDataName();
        infoName.close();
        tvName.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dataName));
```

and this is my DataBase:

```
package com.kalagar.warehouse;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataBase {

    private static final String LOGTAG = "WAREHOUSE";

    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "WareHouse";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "SellList";

    public static final String ROW_ID = "_id";
    public static final String ROW_NAME = "nameOfObject";
    public static final String ROW_KHARID = "ghBuy";
    public static final String ROW_FOROUSH = "ghSell";
    public static final String ROW_PICTURE = "picture";

    private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE
            + " (" + ROW_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + ROW_NAME
            + " TEXT, " + ROW_KHARID + " NUMERIC, " + ROW_FOROUSH
            + " NUMERIC, " + ROW_PICTURE + " TEXT " + ")";

    private WareHouseDdbHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    private static class WareHouseDdbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public WareHouseDdbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
            Log.i(LOGTAG, "Table has been create");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }

    public DataBase(Context c) {
        ourContext = c;
    }

    public DataBase open() throws SQLException {
        ourHelper = new WareHouseDdbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        ourHelper.close();
    }

    public long createEntry(String name, String kharid, String foroush) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(ROW_NAME, name);
        cv.put(ROW_KHARID, kharid);
        cv.put(ROW_FOROUSH, foroush);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

    }

    public ArrayList<String> getDataName() {
        String[] columns = new String[] { ROW_ID, ROW_NAME, ROW_KHARID,
                ROW_FOROUSH };
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
                null, null);
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

        int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(ROW_ID);
        int iName = c.getColumnIndex(ROW_NAME);
        int iKharid = c.getColumnIndex(ROW_KHARID);
        int iForoush = c.getColumnIndex(ROW_FOROUSH);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            result.add(c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iName) + " "
                    + c.getString(iKharid) + " " + c.getString(iForoush));
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use custom listView adapter for this. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/ check this link

Comment: Check my answer in this [link][1] it will surely help you


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953862/creating-listview-dynamically-in-android/14954033#14954033

Comment: You need to use a custom layout and use a custom adapter

Answer (score 0):

for that you need a customize list view first you should add a listview in your main.xml(just an eg) file then create a class like this

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
      private final Context context;
      private final String[] values;
      DataHelper dh;

      public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] values) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;

        dh=new DataHelper(getApplicationContext());
      }

      @Override
      public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_name, parent, false);
       textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textname);

        textView.setText(values[position]);
        // Change the icon for Windows and iPhone
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(View v) 
               {
                   Toast.makeText(this,""+values[position],10000).show();
               }
               });


        return rowView;
} 
}
```

R.layout.list_name this will be the new xml file which will load the contents to the list view

and the the final step just in your on create method do this

```
con = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_listView); 
 MySimpleArrayAdapter adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,  R.id.main_listView ,data);// data is String array valu to be added in list view
    //setting the adapter
    con.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Source [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953862/creating-listview-dynamically-in-android/14954033#14954033)

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom listview adapter fro this.

Here are some examples.

[Android Custom ListView with Image and Text](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

[Using lists in Android (ListView) - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Create an XML for list item of list view.
2. Create a `POJO` class for those data which will be shown as list item.
3. Create a custom adapter using that XML. use `BaseAdapter` to create custom adapter.
4. Suppose, you have created a custom adapter named `CustomAdapter.java` and a `POJO` class named `RowItem.java`. Now assign this adapter into the `Listview` as follows...

   ```
   ListView tvName = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvListOfObject);
   CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, List<RowItem>());
   tvName.setAdapter(adapter);
   ```

You can follow this tutorials...

[Android: Custom ListView with Image and Text using BaseAdapter](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/)

[ListView using BaseAdapter – Android](http://www.pcsalt.com/android/listview-using-baseadapter-android/#sthash.VAG2O6cW.dpbs)