# 2d ArrayList Using ListView

Tags: android, listview

I want to build program looks like this.

[image]

I'm getting confused how i can build it like this. The only possibilities in my mind is only using ListView. But really i already searching in many sites how to make it looks like this, but i didn't found it.

So that i already give the mark in the picture. That data is coming from database. So for the example in the first record contain Ship-001 , CDD, Indah Transport, 5 Nov 2015. And the second record is Ship-002, CDE, Buana Karya, 6 Nov 2015, and so on.

Could u help me to provide me about this ?

Comment: you can normally implement list view concept..

Comment: You can use a custom listview. i think this link is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953862/creating-listview-dynamically-in-android/14954033#14954033

Answer (score 0):

so a listview use data in the form of array. every item in the array, will contain one record, for example, item 1 contains ("Ship-001" , "CDD", "Indah Transport", "5 Nov 2015").

then use the list view to show all the items.

this is a great tutorial for listview
[list view tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)